# Could not open file hello.world

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I went over the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_hello_world&cat=write_plugin), and produced the libhelloworld.so file, I checked env and found GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=:/home/rhexlover/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/build being added. When I ran it, it just didn't open

```
rhexlover@rhexlover-OptiPlex-790:~/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/build$ gzserver ../hello.world --verboseGazebo multi-robot simulator, version 5.1.0 
Copyright (C) 2012-2015 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 128.114.62.230
[Err] [Server.cc:285] Could not open file[../hello.world]
```

What's wrong here?

UPDATE:
I created my model in /home/rhexlover/.gazebo/models/my_robot by following the tutorial. And I added the following to my model's sdf file,

```
<sdf version='1.5'>
<world name="default">
<plugin name="hello_world" filename="libhello_world.so"/>
</world>
<model name="my_robot">
...
```

I click my model in Gazebo, and click again to put it in the world. It doesn't show up and in the terminal it prints the entire content of the model's sdf file.

but the plugin works when I call it directly with gzserver:

```
rhexlover@rhexlover-OptiPlex-790:~/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/build$ $ gzserve ~/.gazebo/models/my_robot/model.sdf --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 5.1.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2015 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 128.114.62.230
Hello World!
^Crhexlover@rhexlover-OptiPlex-790:~/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/build$
```

UPDATE #2:
I think I figured it out. The world tag should not be in model's sdf. When I put my model's sdf into a .world file and the model tag under the world tag, it all works now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8690/could-not-open-file-hello.world/) by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-05-12**:
It seems like the `hello.world` file was not found. Did you copy the world file into `~/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/hello.world`?

**Comment by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on 2015-05-12**:
Yes that was the problem. I didn't have the file. But when I tried to run it from my model, it prints out the entire sdf content. I'll put the setup I have above to show that how it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think I figured it out. The world tag should not be in model's sdf. When I put my model's sdf into a .world file and the model tag under the world tag, it all works now.

---

Originally posted by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) with karma: 17 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0